# Android Things - pico i.mx7 unable to connect

Tags: adb, android-things, fastboot

I've just unpacked my new Pico Pro Maker Kit and started flashing procedure. After creating a product in AndroidThings platform and downloading the build I've started flashing procedure.

Command flash-all.sh failed on fastboot syntax, so I've build that manually and found that it was failing on part "set_active _a". I've skipped that and continued to flash device.

Now device is rebooted, I can see on the screen androidThings logo and version + info about network status ("not connected").

I'm unable to find this device in

```
fastboot devices
```

or

```
adb devices
```

so it looks like I have no way to connect into it.

Do you know a way of fixing that? Is there any way to force fastboot reboot on that device?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to connect board to Ethernet? If it connects, you can use adb.

Comment: Actually the issue was adb server on mac. After adb kill-server it started working.

Comment: It also looks like you may have been using an older version of fastboot. What version of platform tools do you have installed on your development machine?

Answer (score 0):

I had a related problem for IMX7 on initial install, I thought I'd pass along the Boundary feedback in case it helps. Tech support at Boundary devices recommended that I try the following:

> Please try to add **androidboot.dm_verity=disabled** and
>   **androidboot.selinux=disabled** options to bootargs.

I presume these would be options you'd set at the boot prompt `==>` (from the serial connection) but I haven't had a chance to test, which I may get to next week. Interested in your feedback if this has any impact to your situation in the meantime.